# How do I disable csrf protection on gitlab enterprise server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jmeter, gitlab, csrf-protection

I have an internal requirement to stress gitlab to evaluate its performance serving requests for large sized repos with concurrent commits by many engineers. I am using JMeter to record a flow of committing a file from the UI. On replay, I get a 403 because the csrf token validation fails. I have tried extracting the **authenticity_token** via Regex but the value getting used as part of the **X-CSRF_Token** header is different and there is no way for me to extract that value from the preceding response.
For the purposes of my load testing, I want to disable this check in gitlab-rails. Where and how should I go about doing this?